# Asp.Net textbox is not declared error when textbox is in gridview header

Tags: asp.net, gridview, filter

I am adding several textboxes to an asp.net gridview just below the header of each column, in order to use them as filter input fields.

The thing is when I try to run it I get the following error on each field:

```
Error   3   'txtS_AP' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

if I take out the textboxes outside of the gridview, then I get no errors, so I assume there is something "special" about putting fields within the gridview.

I would appreciate if anyone can help on how to avoid this.
thanks

```
<asp:TemplateField >
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbAP" runat="server" Text="AP" style="color:white;" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="AP"></asp:LinkButton> <br />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtS_AP"  CssClass="STD_searchfields" AutoPostBack="true" ></asp:TextBox>
  </HeaderTemplate>     

      <ItemTemplate>                                       
           <table  >
           <tr >
           <td class="STD_normal" style="width:100px;"><%#Eval("AP")%></td>                                                    
           </tr>
            <tr>
           <td class="STD_Normal_Grey" style="width:100px; height:20px"><%#Eval("OUNCKN")%> (<%#Eval("ORC")%>)</td>
           </tr>
           </table>                                           
        </ItemTemplate>                                       
      <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's inside of a container your will have to declare and find it before using. You can do something like this:

VB.NET:

```
Dim txtS_AP As TextBox = GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("txtS_AP")
```

C#

```
TextBox txtS_AP = (TextBox)GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("txtS_AP");
```

Once you do this - you should be able to access all it's properties (here assuming `GridView1` is your grid id.)

Comment: thanks for input. Where exactly do I have to put the Dims ? On the same VB module where the textboxes are used? I've done that and it seems like something is wrong. I don't get an error message now, simply the code jumps the module, like if "on error exit sub" occurs.

Comment: You can declare variable at the beginning of the page class before all the events, and actually assign the `FindControl` value inside of GridView Init event

Comment: regardless where I declare the boxes, I still getting problems...must be something different this time but since I am getting no message errors will need to dig deeper. I appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem. Yes your case may differ in where to declare and where to use it, but the main thing stands - you have to FindControl within the GridView in code.

Comment: Problem found (in case other people read this). I had the gridview display="none"  so first loading of page I assume was not grid rendered and therefore no fields on header row to dim. So before the code runs I make display="" and then it worked!. Thanks Yuriy for taking me in the right direction.